# Can the nested function inside base function be called in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, nested

I recently had an interview in python where the interviewer asked me the below question.

```
def function1():
         print("Am inside function 1")
         pass

         def function2():
                  print("Am inside function 2")

         def function3():
                  print("Am inside function 3")

         function2()
         function3()

         print("Final call")


function1()
```

output:
Am inside function 1
Am inside function 2
Am inside function 3
Final call

Now the question was how can i call function2 outside just like i called function1(). I have tried coming up with answers but ended up in vain. Am not sure if its even possible due to the "pass" being present at function1. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Check the documentation for the Python `pass` statement. It simply does nothing, so execution of `function1` just blows right by it. It doesn't return, it doesn't break. It just doesn't do anything.